# Rouche's theorem equivalent for reals

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

One of the best things I liked about my Complex Analysis course were all the great tools we had to find roots, integrals etc. some tools we couldn't have used in $ \mathbb{R}$.

I know we can use the Residue theorem to solve real integrals, which is cool.
But, is there any way to use Roche's theorem to find how many roots a function has in some subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (probably not), or at least some equivalent theorem?

Comment: Something like that (you will laugh) is the following: If $f :[a,b]\to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous with $f(a)\neq 0\neq f(b)$, then we can define the **mapping degree** of $f$ (w.r.t. $0$) as $sgn(f(b))-sgn(f(a)) \in \Bbb{Z}$. If this is non-zero, $f$ has a zero (intermediate value theorem). One can generalize this to higher dimensions and get non-trivial results (Brouwer fixed point, Borsuk-Ulam,...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, there is a similar concept, called Mapping Degree. For details, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping.

For this degree, we have a similar theorem of Rouche:

*Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be open and bounded such that $0\in\Omega$. Let $f,g:\overline\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ be continuous functions such that $|f(x)|<|g(x)|$ for all $x\in\partial\Omega$. Then $deg(f+g,\Omega,0)=deg(f,\Omega,0)$.*

Comment: Too bad I can't upvote. Thanks!